# Soap Webservies request and response Xml Namespace is different in actual and expected

Tags: xml, spring, web-services, spring-boot, wsdl

I created a soap ws from wsdl in spring boot ws.I has an existing request and response for the same services,new service request and response are of structure of existing service, but the request and response created in spring boot ws has different namespace compared to existing request and response.(e.g. n2:AAA in old and new has n5:AAA). From soapui I tried hitting the spring boot ws with existing request I am getting the response from my new service but still the response namespace is different.I want the response of the new ws should remains same as existing response. 
What would be the problem and how I could able produce the identical response with same namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If the namespace ID isn’t important to the result, you can make SoapUI ignore namespace and just focus on the values in the response.

Comment: Expectation is must to have the same namespace,